# Rendering a string array with handlebars

Tags: handlebars.js

Lets say I have an array like this in ember controller,

```
selectedUsers: ["Popeye", "Sulley", "Gru"];
```

Now, how can i render each users in an unordered list using handlebars? Can i use the `{{#Each}}` helper?

Comment: What's wrong with `each` helper?

Answer (score 102, accepted):

Yes, you should use an `each` loop:

```
<ul>
{{#each selectedUsers}}
    <li>{{ this }}</li>
{{/each}}
</ul>
```

From [the docs](http://handlebarsjs.com/builtin_helpers.html#iteration):

> You can iterate over a list using the built-in `each` helper. Inside the block, you can use `this` to reference the element being iterated over.
>
> ```
> <ul class="people_list">
>   {{#each people}}
>     <li>{{this}}</li>
>   {{/each}}
> </ul>
> ```
>
> when used with this context:
>
> ```
> {
>   people: [
>     "Yehuda Katz",
>     "Alan Johnson",
>     "Charles Jolley"
>   ]
> }
> ```
>
> will result in:
>
> ```
> <ul class="people_list">
>   <li>Yehuda Katz</li>
>   <li>Alan Johnson</li>
>   <li>Charles Jolley</li>
> </ul>
> ```
>
> You can use the this expression in any context to reference the current context.

Comment: Is it possible to use a variable name for the item, rather than `this`? Eg, `selectedUser`?

Answer (score 4):

This also works

```
<ul>
{{#each this}}
<li>{{ this }}</li>
{{/each}}
</ul>
```

Comment: I get "Unclosed section "each this""